# Convert a string representation of a list of tuples to a list when elements are not quoted

Tags: python

I have a string like below:

```
s = '[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)]'
```

How can I convert it to a list of below:

```
[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
```

Please note in the string, the elements are not quoted.

Also, I know it can be done using a lot of splits or regex, is there another way to evaluate it as a list?

Comment: I think the most elegant way should be regex

Comment: What's not elegant about regex. Totally subjective...

Comment: Ok, I've re-phrased my question a bit to be less offensive to some people.

Comment: You'll find people defending regex for this scenario - because it it really is a good solution in this case. Other evaluation and Python parser-based solutions will rely on the values in your tuple meeting certain rules, like being valid Python variable identifiers. Any other type of parser is unlikely to be faster and definitely not going to be shorter. What exactly is the reason not to want to use a split or regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general solution to this would require implementing a parser, but your simple example can be solved with a regex and a list comprehension:

```
>>> import re
>>> [tuple(x.split(',')) for x in re.findall("\((.*?)\)", s)]
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

If you want to use Python's parser to do the parsing for you, you could do something like this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> parsed = ast.parse(s)
>>> [tuple(el.id for el in t.elts) for t in parsed.body[0].value.elts]
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Though keep in mind both these approaches assume your input has a very particular structure.

---

The most complete approach would be to implement a parser specific to the form of the input that you expect, using a tool like https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Here is an example: you can put this parsing code in a module named `parser.py`:

```
# parser.py
import os

import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

class ParserBase:
    """
    Base class for a lexer/parser that has the rules defined as methods
    """
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.debug = kw.get("debug", 0)
        modname = (
            os.path.split(os.path.splitext(__file__)[0])[1]
            + "_"
            + self.__class__.__name__
        )
        self.debugfile = modname + ".dbg"
        self.tabmodule = modname + "_" + "parsetab"

        # Build the lexer and parser
        lex.lex(module=self, debug=self.debug)
        yacc.yacc(
            module=self,
            debug=self.debug,
            debugfile=self.debugfile,
            tabmodule=self.tabmodule,
        )

    def parse(self, expression):
        return yacc.parse(expression)


class Parser(ParserBase):

    tokens = (
        "NAME",
        "COMMA",
        "LPAREN",
        "RPAREN",
        "LBRACKET",
        "RBRACKET",
    )

    # Tokens

    t_COMMA = r","
    t_LPAREN = r"\("
    t_RPAREN = r"\)"
    t_LBRACKET = r"\["
    t_RBRACKET = r"\]"
    t_NAME = r"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"

    def t_error(self, t):
        raise ValueError("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])

    def p_expression(self, p):
        """
        expression : name
                   | list
                   | tuple
        """
        p[0] = p[1]

    def p_name(self, p):
        "name : NAME"
        p[0] = str(p[1])

    def p_list(self, p):
        """
        list : LBRACKET RBRACKET
             | LBRACKET arglist RBRACKET
        """
        if len(p) == 3:
            p[0] = []
        elif len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = list(p[2])

    def p_tuple(self, p):
        """
        tuple : LPAREN RPAREN
              | LPAREN arglist RPAREN
        """
        if len(p) == 3:
            p[0] = tuple()
        elif len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = tuple(p[2])

    def p_arglist(self, p):
        """
        arglist : arglist COMMA expression
                | expression
        """
        if len(p) == 4:
            p[0] = p[1] + [p[3]]
        else:
            p[0] = [p[1]]

    def p_error(self, p):
        if p:
            raise ValueError(f"Syntax error at '{p.value}'")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Syntax error at EOF")
```

Then use it this way:

```
>>> from parser import Parser
>>> p = Parser()
>>> p.parse('[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)]')
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

This should work for arbitrarily-nested inputs:

```
>>> p.parse('[(a,b),(c,d),([(e,f,g),h,i],j)]')
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ([('e', 'f', 'g'), 'h', 'i'], 'j')]
```

And will give you a nice error if your string doesn't match the parsing rules:

```
>>> p.parse('[a,b,c)')
...
ValueError: Syntax error at ')'
```

Comment: Note that both of the solutions in this answer work only for non-nested inputs.

Comment: Also note `ast.parse` would fail if the input contains reserved words (try changing `f` to `if`, for example), which is why I discarded the use of `ast.parse` in my original answer.

Comment: If you don't want to use regexes, and your string is not valid Python, then the best approach would probably be to implement a simple parser using a tool like https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Comment: Also note that `ast.parse` would turn an input such as `(a)` into a single `Name` node rather than a `Tuple` node, which is another reason why I abandoned it.

Comment: OK, added a more complete solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. Have upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Since the input is actually valid Python code, you can properly parse it with `tokenize.generate_tokens`, and enclose each token in single quotes if it is a `NAME` token:

```
from tokenize import generate_tokens, NAME
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO('[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)]')
output = ''.join(f"'{token}'" if token_type == NAME else token
                 for token_type, token, *_ in generate_tokens(file.readline))
```

`output` becomes:

```
 [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/SecondAdmirableNormalform

Comment: The input is not valid Python code, unless the OP wanted to refer to values of variables called `a`, `b`, etc. - or rather, it is valid Python code, but with a different meaning, so your solution only works in specific cases where the values evaluate to variable names

Comment: The input *is* valid Python code. All that needs to be done is to give the variable names the same values as their names, which is exactly what my code does.

Comment: Updated with a more robust and efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

s = '[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)]'

listOfElements = []

for element in re.findall('\(.*?\)',s):
    element = element[1:-1].split(',')
    listOfElements.append((element[0],element[1]))
```

That's not a lot of splits/regex :D

Comment: Sorry, I specifically mentioned I need a non-regex solution here.

Comment: You said without a lot of regex/splits. It's one split and one regex!